# Why Java Nashorn __DIR__, __LINE__ and __FILE__ are null?

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, scriptengine, nashorn

I am trying to get `__DIR__`, `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` **Nashorn globals** within JavaScript file which is compiled and evaluated by Java Nashorn Engine (JDK 8).

However, all of them return **NULL**...

Are they related to some specific Nashorn configuration or? It doesn't say anything in the [documentation](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions) about any additional configuration to get them working.

Comment: Works for me... how are you invoking Nashorn? Note, `__DIR__` is null if `jjs` is reading from stdin.

Comment: I am using Nashorn from Java. Evaluating `CompiledScript` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but as I came up with a simple solution I wanted to share it to help people that face the same issue.

In fact you can easily have `__FILE__`, `__DIR__`, and `__LINE__` working if instead of doing the usual:

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("path_to_your_js"));
```

You actually call a small JS code that  load your file:

```
engine.eval("load('path_to_your_js')");
```

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you. I would also add though, that whilst this worked perfectly on my Apple Mac, for targeting Windows I found it necessary to escape the backslashes in the  pathname. i.e.

   pathname = pathname.replace("\\", "\\\\");
   engine.eval("load(\"" + pathname + "\")";

Answer (score 1):

This is because you probably loaded the script as a String. Most examples are like this:

```
engine.eval(new FileReader("scripts/hello.js"));
```

Then the engine does not know, where this script came from, because it only gets the response from the FileReader. It's like calling `engine.eval("print('hello')")`, there is no file, just a string.

If you call your script from console, using `jjs`, they're filled correctly.

To achive this from Java, I currently only see a dirty one: Save your file path as string in the context and access this from js:

```
ScriptContext ctx = engine.getContext();
ctx.getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put("thisFile", script);

engine.eval(new FileReader(script), defCtx);
```

The js:

```
print("I am " + thisFile);
```

Output:

```
I am resources/test.js
```

**Note**: But it has to be possible, because `jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell` is able to set up a `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context` where this is set in an Array of globals.